# Fixed bottom menu on mobile doesn't work on search included in Child Theme of Storefront

Tags: customization, child-theme

I included footer of parent theme "Storefront" into the footer of my own child theme that I have created. The main purpose is having a fixed bottom menu on mobile version.

It is all working well, except for the search icon. When I click on it, it doesn't toggle up like the parent theme does. Do I have to do anything else or is there any jquery/ajax code I was supposed to included to make the search work like the parent theme. Does anybody can please help me on this problem? 
The site I am working on is: https://test5.extensionesdepelobaratas.net/

Thank you very much.

Comment: please add footer css class for ul li

Comment: all class are exactly the same to each other because I copy and paste the code from the parent theme into the child theme.